# Search all database with varchar and INT fields with wildcard mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get a wildcard search to pick up on any text in org_name field and also to pick up any INT fields that have a 1 in them are entered into the form,

e,g If someone types Childminder in the form I want all records with the childminder INT field with a 1 in it to show up on the results...

```
$sql_result= "SELECT * FROM table WHERE org_name LIKE '%" . $org_name . "%' 

OR carer LIKE '1'
OR childminder LIKE '1' ";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would do such things, but sounds like a candidate to the manual query concatenation (hint: don't do this, it hurts). PDO does not support binding column names, so you're out of luck if you're trying to have any help from libraries / other estabilished solutions.

**Update**

If your schema does not change and you're concerned about SQLi, you could have some matching mechanism that would take search query and array of available ("matchable") columns and process them, reporting matching columns. Then you would just make query from the safe data. Sample code:

```
$columns = array(/* ... */);
$query = '/* ... */';
$matches = array();
foreach($columns as $column) 
    { 
    if(preg_match('/'.$column.'/', $query)) 
        { 
        $matches[] = $column; 
        } 
    }

$sqlQuery = 'you select';
foreach($matches as $match)
    {
    $sqlQuery .= ' OR '.$match.' = 1';
    }
```

Not exact code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Its a pain, but I'm limited in that I cant change the database. I'm also very concerned about an injection attack.

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm lost on how I could implement in my set up. Could I post my whole code?

Comment: Please specify, what you don't "get". I'll be happy to explain.

Comment: If you have no further questions, please upvote and accept. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12579/discussion-between-stephen-and-tomasz-kowalczyk)